# How to configure "Unused Declarations" settings from an Intellij IDEA plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In Intellij IDEA Community, if you work on a REST application (JavaEE, Micronaut, Quarkus...), public methods annotated with whatever framework annotation (eg. `javax.ws.rs.GET`) are shown as "unused". Now you can go in `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inspections` > `Java` > `Unused Declaration [Entry points tab]`, and manually configure annotations to ignore.

In Intellij IDEA Ultimate, this works out-of-the-box, even though the "Unused Declaration" annotations don't appear to be configured.

Now, I'm writing an Intellij plugin, and would very much like to be able to also exclude those annotations from the "Unused Declaration", either via plugin.xml or programmatic configuration via some Intellij API.

I've looked for some plugin.xml configurations or examples of UnusedDeclarationInspection usages but to no avail. I don't want to create a new inspection, just configure an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the interface `com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.ImplicitUsageProvider`. When implemented it:

> Allows to disable highlighting of certain elements as unused when such elements are not referenced from the code but are referenced in some other way. For example,
>
> - from generated code
> - from outside containers: @javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet public class MyServlet {}
> - from some frameworks: @javax.ejb.EJB private DataStore myInjectedDataStore;
>   etc

You will need to register the implementation in your `plugin.xml` file using something like:
`<implicitUsageProvider implementation="my.package.MyImplicitUsageProvider"/>`